# Deprecating function in external API

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm using an external proprietary library API which has marked in their documentation various functions as deprecated but have not provided any features (compile flags, macros etc) to flag use of the deprecated functions. I would like to flag use of these functions at compile time.

Various things I've attempted but haven't had any success with include:

1. Marking the functions with the deprecated attribute `[[deprecated]]` in my own header which includes the API header. Tried various permutations generally resulting in errors for out-of-line declarations
2. Creating my own class that inherits from the API class and using (`using A::B`) all required functions and then deleting the deprecated functions. This creates a longer term maintenance issues with the library when supporting upgrades
3. Using `#pragma GCC poison`, but as this works on tokens and doesn't understand classes would be a hammer to a token that might be used as a variable name

Last option I have considered and want to avoid is creating a script to identify the functions and use this script in a CI tool and git hook, though I would rather know at compile time I am using a deprecated function than during the CI or commit phase.

Comment: Can't you ask the supplier of this library to mark the functions as `[[deprecated]]` in the library too?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, and I plan to, but that does not assist for the current version of the library, and they may choose to not implement the request. Question is about how I can work around the current state as they have not currently provided any features to flag use of these functions

Comment: For point 2, can't you use composition instead of inheritance. Basically, writing a wrapper for the library with similar function signatures and then marking specific functions as deprecated with appropriate warning message?

Comment: @kiner_shah yes, though this contributes to the maintenance issue (e.g. managing upgrades to the library) and won't prevent other developers from using the API directly and bypassing the wrapper. It would also mean updating all existing references in the codebase to use the new wrapper class and function names

Comment: Then your only option is to ask the vendor to provide library with deprecation warnings. You should state your issues clearly to them and how it can affect the quality of your solution.

Comment: Instead of a script that detects the use, perhaps you could mock the deprecated functions and make unit tests fail if they are used? That way users won't have to wait for CI. They'll get the feedback from the unit tests directly.